# filtering an elasticsearch query by aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi my question is two parts.
I've got a dataset that looks like

```
{name: "foo", 
 contracts: [{size: 1}, {size: 3}]},
{name: "bar", 
 contracts: [{size: 100}, {size: 300}]}
```

using the metrics aggregation I can the average size of ALL the items. 1+3+100+300 / 4,
however is it possible to return the average contract size per item?

I'd like to be able to return

```
{name: "foo", 
 averageContract: 2}, 
{name: "bar", 
 averageContract: 200},
```

Additionally would it be possible to get that value AND filter on it?

e.g. match where averageContract > 100 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "item": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "averageContract": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "contracts.size"
          }
        },
        "selector_avg_contract": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "avg": "averageContract"
            },
            "script": "params.avg > 100"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is great! It definitely gives me the data I need except it doesn't seem to filter out the actual documents with avg < 100.

Comment: it appears to only filter out the buckets themselves

Comment: I forgot to add the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html